# flask blueprint for custom static folder not working in templates using url_for

Tags: static-files, flask

I am trying to use a blueprint to serve some of my js and css files from a folder than `/static`.  I want these files to be available from the root. I have registered the following blueprint with the app:

```
custom = Blueprint('/', __name__, static_folder='custom', static_url_path='/custom')
app.register_blueprint(custom)
```

I can find the desired files in the expected place, ie. `/custom/custom.css` by putting this url directly into the browser, however, I am not able to access them in templates using url_for like this:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('custom', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I get: `BuildError: ('custom', {'filename': 'style.css'}, None)`

I have tried any number of combinations ie.:

```
custom = Blueprint('custom', __name__, static_folder='custom', static_url_path='/custom')
```

with

```
<link href="{{ url_for('custom.custom', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

etc but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the blueprint's static endpoint.

```
url_for('custom.static', filename='custom.css')
```

Comment: damn, so simple.  I tried it before, but must have been in combination with something else in the blueprint registration that was wrong.  Thanks, man!